# HTML nested div not displaying

Tags: html, css, nested

I have created a div. The CSS entry is as below:

```
.displaybox
{    
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    border: 1px solid;
    background:#F0F0F0;
    font-family:arial,sans-serif;
    position:absolute;
    overflow:auto;
    padding:5px;
}
```

I then use the following HTML to display it:

```
    <div class="displaybox" id="RawScanDisplay" style="display:none;"></div>
```

So far this works fine.

I now want a nested div to display inside, which is purely for display purposes.

I created a simple div, which I can manipulate later to display as I want. The div is as follows:

```
<div style="background:#AABCC1; height:20px; width:20px;"></div>
```

This div displays fine on its own, but when I try to nest it within the intended parent div, it does not display, as below:

```
    <div class="displaybox" id="RawScanDisplay" style="display:none;"><div style="background:#AABCC1; height:20px; width:20px;"></div></div>
```

I want the parent div to be hidden until the user performs a particular action, at which time I want it to display, below is the javascript:

```
        function fnRawScanDataResponse(e)
        {            
            var oBox = document.getElementById("RawScanDisplay");
            oBox.style.display = "";

        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: parent is set to display:none so you need to move the nested div outside

Comment: coz the parent DIV is hidden.. it'll apply to its children too.. just remove the display:none for parent.. and it'll work fine..

Comment: remove {style="display:none;"} from the parent div

Comment: [That's what display:none does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

Answer (score 5):

When You apply styles `display:none` to container, each element of this container disappears also.

You can use `visibility: hidden` instead to get effect that container still takes spaces of window, but content disappears also in this case